# Overriding React Component's prototype method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have the following React Component class:

```
class SayHello extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return <div onClick={this.handleOnClick}>Click Me</div>;
    }

    handleOnClick() {
        console.log("clicked");
    }
}
```

What I want to do is create a higher order component that knows about the `handleOnClick` in `SayHello` but **before** calling `SayHello`'s `handleOnClick`, I want it to execute some code I pass in first (i.e. I want to run code that logs something in my server).

Is there a React pattern for doing something like this?

**EDIT:**

I want to provide some more context here. I want my higher order component to be dynamic in terms of which methods to call. For example, sometimes it might be `handleOnClick` but other times it might be `handleOnSomethingElse`.

Comment: Is the custom "before component method" code dynamic as well?

Comment: Yes in the sense that I would want it to just mirror the method that's in the SayHello component. So if I'm trying to override SayHello's handleOnClick, then it'd be beforeHandleOnClick, and if its SayHello's handleSomethingElse, it'd be beforeHandleSomethingElse.

Comment: OK, I've added another answer. I left the first because I think it will help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like a dynamic [mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin).

This higher-order component takes a Component class and an Object of decorator methods.

The HOC wraps each method that has a matching decorator. These methods call the decorator then call through to the original component method. Non-decorated methods are unchanged.

```js
// Higher-order component
function decorateMethods(componentClass, decorators) {
  class decoratedClass extends componentClass { }

  Object.keys(decorators).forEach(decoratorName => {
    decoratedClass.prototype[decoratorName] = function(...args) {
      decorators[decoratorName].call(this, ...args);
      return componentClass.prototype[decoratorName].call(this, ...args)
    }
  })
  
  return decoratedClass
}

//
// Test 
//
class Component {
  foo() {
    console.log("foo")
  }
  
  bar() {
    console.log("bar")
  }
  
  baz() {
    console.log("baz")
  }
}

const DecoratedComponent = decorateMethods(Component, {
  foo() {
    console.log("before foo")
  },
  
  bar() {
    console.log("before bar")
  }
})

const d = new DecoratedComponent()
d.foo()
d.bar()
d.baz()
```

In this case the decorator methods exactly match the base class method names. If you want the decorator to use, e.g. `beforeFoo` instead, you could map method names with:

```
const methodName = decoratorName replace(/before(\w)/, (_, a) => a.toLowerCase())
```

Comment: Ah I see - I had a similar idea except I kept on trying to call `super[decoratorName]` and my console output threw an error about `super being called outside of the class`. This is super helpful - thank you!

Answer (score 6):

A [higher-order component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) is a function that takes a component argument and returns a new component.

This function returns a component with a decorated `handleClick` method:

```
// A higher-order component that runs some code before
// the given component's `handleClick` method
function wrapHello(componentClass) {
  return class wrapped extends componentClass {
    beforeHandleClick() {
      console.log("I run first!")
    }

    handleClick(...args) {
      this.beforeHandleClick()
      super.handleClick(...args)
    }
  }
}
```

[This pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) is neat because it isn't specific to React at all; it's just a [pure function](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-pure-function-d1c076bec976). That means it's easy to test and reason about.

Here's a test harness that doesn't use React:

```js
function wrapHello(componentClass) {
  return class wrapped extends componentClass {
    beforeHandleClick() {
      console.log("I run first!")
    }

    handleClick(...args) {
      this.beforeHandleClick()
      super.handleClick(...args)
    }
  }
}

class SayHello {
  handleClick() {
    console.log("handleClick")
  }
}

const WrappedHello = wrapHello(SayHello)
new WrappedHello().handleClick()
```

Comment: thanks for this example - I was able to come up with something similar as well. The struggle I'm having is I want to make the wrapped component dynamic in terms of knowing which methods to decorate. I'll provide more context in my original question.